# Substituir valor depois da tag, mas dentro da div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho o código HTML, e preciso fazer a substituição do valor decimal no fim da div, o projeto é fazendo um proxy reverso de um site, e tenho que por o valor da tag "changed" no lugar onde está o "11.00"
o HTML é este:

```
<div class="osg-outcome__price" changed="7.14">
    <i class="osg-outcome__trend"></i>
    11.00
</div>
```

Já tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var value = parseFloat($(this).text());
var ht = $(this).html().replace(value,$(this).attr("changed"));
$(this).html(ht);
```

Mas o problema é que o valor da div muda constantemente com base em um websocket, aí quando altero o valor dessa forma, o websocket para de atualizar a div por algum motivo.
O máximo que consegui foi colocar o valor de interesse dentro da tag 'changed', agora preciso levar esse valor para div sem tocar no `<i class="osg-outcome__trend">`.

Existe uma forma de fazer isso no CSS? Creio que evitaria esses problemas. Ou uma solucação *jQuery* mais precisa?

Comment: Tente colocar o valor **11.00** em alguma tag (span, p, div) e coloque um id ou classe aí na váriavel ht chame por este id ou classe.

Answer (score 1):

Adiciona `.toFixed(2)` ao `value` nesta linha do `replace`:

```
var ht = $(this).html().replace(value.toFixed(2),$(this).attr("changed"));
```

O `parseFloat` dispensa os zeros das decimais:

```
11.00 --> 11
11.10 --> 11.1
```

Assim o `replace` não vai funcionar porque não irá encontrar o valor corretamente. O `toFixed(2)` irá manter os zeros também:

```
11.00 --> 11.00
11.10 --> 11.10
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas ainda não deu! então fiz o seguinte, ocultei o valor original com `$(this).css("display","none");` e depois adicionei uma nova div com o valor `$(this).parent("div").append("<div id='changed'>"+baixado+"</div>")`; então pra atualizar o valor eu usei um condição que checa se a div de id changed existe, se existir ele atualiza, se não existir ele cria.

Comment: O `<i class="osg-outcome__trend">` tb recebe algum texto?